# How to specify where html goes in a Blazor Component

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

Let's say I have a file called component1.razor and in that file I have the following code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item1" > </div>
    <div class="item2" > </div>
</div>
```

now in another file use that component like this:

```
<component1> 
    <!-- I add more html here -->
    <h3>Text</h3>
    <p>more text</p>
</component1>
```

which div is the content inside the component put in, item1 or item2?
and how can I specify which to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define parameters in your component.
Component1.razor

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item1">@Item1</div>
    <div class="item2">@Item2</div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Item1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<Component1>
    <Item1><h3>Text</h3></Item1>
    <Item2><p>more text</p></Item2>
</Component1>
```

See: [Build reusable UI components with Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components)